# I have a SQL table column with this value '0x000000001903A06C'. and the column name is 'mr_timestamp'

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table column with this value '0x000000001903A06C', and the column name is 'mr_timestamp'. Not sure what is the format and how to make this value readable. How can I interpret this value?

Comment: What is the datatype of the column?

Comment: The type is `rowversion`. It's a binary(8) type, so the format you see is how to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be sure without seeing the exact definition for the column, but it looks like this isn't actually a time stamp value as we normally think of time stamps, in spite of the `mr_timestamp` name. Instead, it looks like a [`rowversion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).  Rowversion tracks a *relative* time to that database column rather than anything associated with a clock. The only things it's useful for is sorting rows by which was changed most (or least) recently.

To help explain the `mr_timestamp` name, the SQL Server `timestamp` type is an alias for `rowversion`. If you really need timestamps, you should use `datetime` or `datetime2` instead.

In other words, what you've shown is already all there is; there's nothing to change that will make the value any more readable.

In fact, the type is actually **deprecated**, meaning it should no longer be used for new work, and removed from old as the opportunity presents.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the alternative for rowversion? I guess datime2 does not have high enough resolution?

Comment: If 100ns is not enough resolution, you have other problems. But if I had to, I'd solve it with a [`SEQUENCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).